# Does AWS give you a default ssl cert on their amazonaws.com subdomains like GAE and appspot.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

When I deploy apps on Google App Engine, they automatically get use of the appspot.com wildcard SSL cert allowing me to have https secure URLs.
Does AWS give you this option, or is installing your own SSL cert the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon only provides free SSL certs through the [ACM service](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/), which is currently restricted to CloudFront distributions and Elastic Load Balancers that you have configured with your own custom domain name.

There are other ways to obtain a free SSL cert if you own your own domain name, such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).